# How to get a 409 for ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that Spring Boot will render a Thymeleaf template at `error/409.html` for an exception that leads to a statuscode of 409 CONFLICT by default. However, it seems that `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` gives a 500 SERVER ERROR by default.

I am able to handle the exception and "manually" redirect to the `error/409.html` template using a `@ControllerAdvice` like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler({DataIntegrityViolationException.class, ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class})
    public ModelAndView handleConflict(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("error/409");
        result.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Since `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is not part of my own code, I cannot annotate it with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)` to have a 409.

Is it possible to map `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` to 409 and use the default error template mechanism for error codes in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

We can try with ResponseEntity as below

```
    @ExceptionHandler({DataIntegrityViolationException.class, ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ModelAndView> handleConflict(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("error/409");
    result.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
    @Bean(name="simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver
                  createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r =
                new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.setProperty("ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException", "error/409");


    r.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    return r;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you catch the exception `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and re-throw an exception with 409?

```java
try {
    //perform your task here
} catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
    var ex = new ClientErrorException(409, e);
    throw ex;
}
```